# How to generate custom URL for React Survey web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, redux, survey

I am making a Survey app. 
The stack will be React + Redux + postgresql + heroku + Stripe.

The idea is that Business Owner is able to create a Survey. 
For example 5 question and after he will send it for 10 people.

All 10 people will get a unique url which will point then to the survey.

After completing survey the business owner should see the results on his web statistics.

It there is a library which allows you generate unique url for surveys? Or how it may be implemented?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomstring

Comment: I'm flagging this as `too broad`; it does not actually ask anything related to `reactjs`, `node.js`, `postgresql` and others. Purely business logic question. Try to edit the question to make more not-broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use node.js as a backend. In that case, I recommend using:
crypto.randomBytes(size).toString('hex') ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback))

As the documentation states, it uses a cryptographically strong random data generator. This is important, otherwise, it might be possible that someone can guess your generated id's based on previous ones.

Using a third party library would only introduce unnecessary risks of bugs or unsafe implementations.

For choosing an appropriate size you might want to read this:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insufficient_Session-ID_Length
 As your random Url is just some kind of a session id, this applies to your case as well.

**Other important things to consider:**

- Having a brute force defense that blocks IP's after a certain amount of failed guesses for a certain time
- Logging failed attempts to be able to spot attacks.
- Invalidating the URLS after one use. Otherwise, private information could be leaked or you might expose the surveys to not invited people. This is because the URL might be opened on a public computer and stays in the browser history.

EDIT: You might want to read [owasp.org](http://owasp.org) in general as it contains valuable web security information that could help you make your app more secure.